# Why the runnable stops in my widget?

Tags: java, android, widget, runnable, traffic

I have the following code that updates me on a TextView the total data traffic in MB. At first when you load the widget on the screen runs but then stops.
I checked the Runnable with Log.d and it stops running. Why?.
Can you help me?

```
public class TdWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static long mStartRX = 0;
private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
RemoteViews remoteViews;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
ComponentName thisWidget;

public void init(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager)
{
    mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, TdWidget.class);

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {        
    init(context, appWidgetManager);       
}

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Log.d("Runnable","*********RUNNABLE*******");
        float dwBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
        float dwBytesf = dwBytes/1048576;           

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtshow, "MB Dwn= " + String.format("%.2f", dwBytesf));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a try..if i followed your question clearly.

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Log.d("Runnable","*********RUNNABLE*******");
        another();
    }
    private void another(){
        float dwBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
        float dwBytesf = dwBytes/1048576;           
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtshow, "MB Dwn= " + String.format("%.2f", dwBytesf));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

        try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }catch(Exception ex){  Log.e("Exception"," : "+ex.getMessage())  }

        another();

    }

};
```

Comment: It not works, another method cannot resolved. but Thanks!!

Comment: where you got this line in code.. "another method cannot resolved"

Comment: The another(); into another() and otherwise in private void another() ";" expected when it not requered.

Comment: i putted it in my class and there is no error accept the semi collon after Log statement in sleep block..

Comment: I can execute your code sourabh, but it not works. The Log does not show any errors.The widget stops in OnEnabled and i dont know the reason